# Android. Как поднять Layout с клавиатурой

Tags: android, клавиатура, android-manifest, scrollview

Когда выдвигается клавиатура, layout поднимается, но чуть-чуть. В Xml есть два edit(Email и Password) поля и ниже кнопка (LOGIN). Не могу понять, как правильно это сделать. У меня получилось сделать это только вместе со ScrollView, но меня этот вариант не устраивает. Хотел бы узнать, как можно сделать так, чтоб layout нормально поднимался и расстояние между кнопкой и клавиатурой было 40-50dp (примерно).

P.S. В Манифесте прописывал.

Comment: В iOS есть слушатели событий - появления и исчезновения клавиатуры. Я думаю в Android обязано быть что то подобное. При появлении клавиатуры вычисляем ее высоту, высоту EditText и проводим нужные манипуляции, можно даже с анимацией. Попробуйте покопать в эту сторону

Comment: В манифесте прописан `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`?

Comment: @YuraIvanov да. Я всеми компонентами (windowSoftInputMode) пробовал что либо сделать, но не получается.